# Как удалить лишнюю нагрузку Visual Studio 2019?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2019

Вообщем при установке нагрузок установил одну лишнюю, так как это мой первый опыт в работе с VS, не знаю как теперь удалить лишнюю нагрузку, кто нибудь знает?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Думаю, достаточно запустить Visual Studio Installer, перейти к Modify и там добавить / удалить установленные компоненты:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]